# Series Comparison Test Manipulation

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I know how to do $b$ but I am unsure on $a$. Can someone check both please ?

$(a)$ Using the definition of series convergence, prove that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{b_n}$ converge, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}}$ converges.

If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}$ converges, then $s_N$ $=$ $\sum_{n=1}^{N}{a_n}$ converges. If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{b_n}$ converges, then $t_N$ $=$ $\sum_{n=1}^{N}{b_n}$ converges.

Then I think I should apply algebra of limits / linearity of summation but I am unsure.

$(b)$ By first establishing that $2xy \leq x^2+y^2$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb R$, or otherwise, show that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{b_n}$ are convergent series of NONNEGATIVE terms, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\sqrt{a_n b_n}}$ converges.

We know that $(x-y)^2 \geq 0$, so $x^2 - 2xy + y^2 \geq 0$, so $2xy \leq x^2+y^2$. Using this inequality, we have $2xy \leq (x+y)^2 - 2xy$, so $4xy \leq (x+y)^2$. So $xy \leq \frac{(x+y)^2}{4}$, so $\sqrt{xy} \leq \frac{x+y}{2}$. (This is assuming $x,y$ are non-negative).

Applying this inequality with $x= a_n$ and $y=b_n$, we have $\sqrt{a_nb_n} \leq \frac{a_n+b_n}{2}$. In $(a)$ we proved that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}}$ converges if the individual series converge, so by comparison test, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}}$ converges. $\square$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (a), let $\varepsilon>0$ and choose $N_1$, $N_2$ such that $\left|\sum_{n=1}^m a_i-a\right|<\varepsilon$ for $m\geqslant N_1$ and $\left|\sum_{n=1}^m b_i-b\right|<\varepsilon$ for $m\geqslant N_2$, where $a$ and $b$ are the limits of the respective series. Then for $m\geqslant \max\{N_1,N_2\}$,
\begin{align}
\left|\sum_{n=1}^m \frac{a_n+b_n}2 -\frac{a+b}2 \right| &\leqslant \frac12\left|\sum_{n=1}^ma_n-a\right|\left|\sum_{n=1}^mb_n-b\right| \\
&<\frac12(\varepsilon+\varepsilon)\\
&=\varepsilon,
\end{align}
so that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n+b_n}2$ converges.

For (b), we can use the AM-GM inequality, that is, for nonnegative numbers $x,y$, it holds that $\sqrt{xy}\leqslant\frac{x+y}2$ with equality if and only if $x=y$. Then for all $n$ we have
$$
\sqrt{a_nb_n}\leqslant \frac{a_n+b_n}2,
$$
Then
$$
\sum_{n=1}^m\sqrt{a_nb_n} \leqslant\frac12\sum_{n=1}^m(a_n+b_n)=\frac12\left(\sum_{n=1}^ma_n +\sum_{n=1}^mb_n\right)
$$
for all positive integers $m$, and taking the limit as $m\to\infty$ yields the result.

Comment: I understand $(a)$ now. Did I make many mistakes with $(b)$?